# Getting Error while running the Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi All I am getting an error while running below procedure like

> Encountered the symbol "END" while expecting below symbol  :=)

My procedure is created with:

```
create or replace procedure employee_details is 
cursor emp_cur is select ename,desig,salary from emp; 
emp_rec emp_cur%rowtype; 
begin   
  for emp_rec in sales_cur
  loop       
    dbms_output.put_line(emp_cur.ename||''||emp_cur.desig||''||emp_cur.salary);
  end loop; 
end; 
/
```

I am trying to run like:

```
begin 
    employee_details
End;
```

Comment: Please mark up the code parts.

Comment: Where is `sales_cur` defined?

Answer (score 2):

If you're really calling the procedure as:

```
begin employee_details End;
```

... then you're missing a semicolon; it should be:

```
begin employee_details; end;
```

Or maybe more generally formatted as:

```
begin
    employee_details;
end;
/
```

It isn't really clear if that is your problem since the procedure won't compile as shown, due to the `emp_cur`/`sales_cur` name mismatch noted the comments.